# Kubernetes Flannel k8s_install-cni_kube-flannel-ds exited on worker node

Tags: kubernetes, flannel

I am setting up my very first Kubernetes cluster. We are expecting to have mix of Windows and Linux node so I picked flannel as my cni. I am using RHEL 7.7 as my master node and I have two other RHEL 7.7 machines as worker node and then rest are Windows Server 2019. For most of the part, I was following documentation provided on Microsoft site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/kubernetes/getting-started-kubernetes-windows and also one on Kubernetes site: https://kubernetes.cn/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/adding-windows-nodes/ . I know article on Microsoft site is more than 2 years old but this is only the guide I found for mixed mode operations.

I have done following so far on Master and worker RHEL nodes:

1. stopped and disabled firewalld
2. disabled selinux
3. update && upgrade
4. Disabled swap partition
5. Added /etc/hosts entry for all nodes involved in my Kubernetes cluster
6. Installed Docker CE 19.03.11
7. Install kubectl, kubeadm and kubelet 1.18.3 (Build date 2020-05-20)
8. Prepare Kubernetes control plane for Flannel: `sudo sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1`

I have now done following on RHEL Master node

**Initialize cluster**

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --service-cidr=10.96.0.0/12
```

**kubectl as non-root user**

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

**Patch the Daemon set for the node selector**

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/SDN/master/Kubernetes/flannel/l2bridge/manifests/node-selector-patch.yml
kubectl patch ds/kube-proxy --patch "$(cat node-selector-patch.yml)" -n=kube-system
```

After the patch, kube-proxy looks like this:

[image: kube-system ds]

**Add Flannel**

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

Modify the net-conf.json section of the flannel manifest in order to set the VNI to 4096 and the Port to 4789. It should look as follows:

```
net-conf.json: |
    {
      "Network": "10.244.0.0/16",
      "Backend": {
        "Type": "vxlan",
        "VNI" : 4096,
        "Port": 4789
      }
    }
```

**Apply modified kube-flannel**

```
kubectl apply -f kube-flannel.yml
```

After adding network, here is what I get for pods in kube-system
[image]

**Add Windows Flannel and kube-proxy DaemonSets**

```
curl -L https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-windows-tools/releases/latest/download/kube-proxy.yml | sed 's/VERSION/v1.18.0/g' | kubectl apply -f -
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/sig-windows-tools/releases/latest/download/flannel-overlay.yml
```

**Join Worker node**
I am now trying to join the RHEL 7.7 worker node by executing the kubeadm join command generated when IU initialized my cluster.
Worker node initializes fine as seen below:
[image: worker node initialized]

when I go to my RHEL worker node, I see that *k8s_install-cni_kube-flannel-ds-amd64-f4mtp_kube-system* container is exited as seen below:
[image: cni not workinge]

1. Can you please let me know if I am following the correct procedure? I believe Flannel CNI is required to talk to pods within kubernetes cluster
2. If Flannel is difficult to setup for mixed mode, can we use other network which can work?
3. If we decide to go only and only RHEL nodes, what is the best and easiest network plugin I can install without going through lot of issues?

Thanks and I appreciate it.

Comment: The fact that your container (install-cni...) exited with code 0 should indicate that the provisioning of flannel was correct. Yes you are correct that CNI is required for communication of pods. To check if your CNI is working you can spawn 2 pods on 2 different nodes and try make a connection between them (like ping them). Please let me know the results. As for the last question it really depends what features are you going to need with your CNI. Take a  look for example [here](https://rancher.com/blog/2019/2019-03-21-comparing-kubernetes-cni-providers-flannel-calico-canal-and-weave/).

Comment: Dawid, Thanks for your comment. I am currently experimenting with nginx deployment which comes with minimum installation of Linux kernal. I can get into container with exec command but while in container, I can't use ping since it says command not fount. I tried apt install and it says unable to locate package "iputils-ping". Is there any way I can test ping from this minimum linux container? I am sorry if I am asking question which might not make sense but I am very new to all these and trying to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of materials about Kubernetes on official site and I encourage you to check it out:

- [Kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/)

I divided this answer on parts:

- CNI
- Troubleshooting

---

### CNI

What is CNI?

> CNI (Container Network Interface), a Cloud Native Computing Foundation project, consists of a specification and libraries for writing plugins to configure network interfaces in Linux containers, along with a number of supported plugins. CNI concerns itself only with network connectivity of containers and removing allocated resources when the container is deleted. Because of this focus, CNI has a wide range of support and the specification is simple to implement.
>
> --  *[Github.com: Containernetworking: CNI](https://github.com/containernetworking/cni)*

Your CNI **plugin** in simple terms is responsible for pod's networking inside your cluster.

There are multiple CNI plugins like:

- Flannel
- Calico
- Multus
- Weavenet

What I mean about that, you don't need to use `Flannel`. You can use other plugin like `Calico`. The major consideration is that they are [different](https://rancher.com/blog/2019/2019-03-21-comparing-kubernetes-cni-providers-flannel-calico-canal-and-weave/) from each other and you should pick option best for your use case (support for some feature for example).

There are a lot of materials/resources on this topic. Please take a look at some of them:

- [Youtube.com: Kubernetes and the CNI: Where We Are and What's Next - Casey Callendrello, CoreOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vn6KYkNevBQ)
- [Youtube.com: Container Network Interface (CNI) Explained in 7 Minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2BS_kuQxBA)
- [Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Cluster administration: Networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/)

As for:

> If Flannel is difficult to setup for mixed mode, can we use other network which can work?

If you mean mixed mode by using nodes that are Windows and Linux machines, I would stick to guides that are already written like one you mentioned: [Kubernetes.io: Adding Windows nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/adding-windows-nodes/)

As for:

> If we decide to go only and only RHEL nodes, what is the best and easiest network plugin I can install without going through lot of issues?

The best way to choose CNI plugin would entail looking for solution fitting your needs the most. You can follow this link for an overview:

- [Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Cluster administration: Networking](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/)

Also you can look here (Please have in mind that this article is from 2018 and could be outdated):

- [Itnext.io: Benchmark results of Kubernetes network plugin cni over 10gbit's network](https://itnext.io/benchmark-results-of-kubernetes-network-plugins-cni-over-10gbit-s-network-36475925a560)

---

### Troubleshooting

> when I go to my RHEL worker node, I see that k8s_install-cni_kube-flannel-ds-amd64-f4mtp_kube-system container is exited as seen below:

**Your `k8s_install-cni_kube-flannel-ds-amd64-f4mtp_kube-system` container exited with status `0` which should indicate correct provisioning.**

You can check the logs of flannel pods by invoking below command:

- `kubectl logs POD_NAME`

You can also refer to official documentation of Flannel: [Github.com: Flannel: Troubleshooting](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/troubleshooting.md)

As I said in the comment:

> To check if your CNI is working you can spawn 2 pods on 2 different nodes and try make a connection between them (like ping them).

Steps:

- Spawn pods
- Check their IP addresses
- Exec into pods
- Ping

#### Spawn pods

Below is **example** deployment definition that will spawn ubuntu pods. They will be used to check if pods have communication between nodes:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ubuntu
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ubuntu
  replicas: 5 
  template: 
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ubuntu
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ubuntu
        image: ubuntu:latest
        command:
        - sleep
        - infinity
```

Please have in mind that this example is for testing purposes only. Apply above definition with:

- `kubectl apply -f FILE_NAME.yaml`

#### Check their IP addresses

After pods spawned you should be able to run command:

- `$ kubectl get pods -o wide`

and see output similar to this:

```sh
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE                                         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
ubuntu-557dc88445-lngt7   1/1     Running   0          8s    10.20.0.4   NODE-1   <none>           <none>
ubuntu-557dc88445-nhvbw   1/1     Running   0          8s    10.20.0.5   NODE-1   <none>           <none>
ubuntu-557dc88445-p8v86   1/1     Running   0          8s    10.20.2.4   NODE-2   <none>           <none>
ubuntu-557dc88445-vm2kg   1/1     Running   0          8s    10.20.1.9   NODE-3   <none>           <none>
ubuntu-557dc88445-xwt86   1/1     Running   0          8s    10.20.0.3   NODE-1   <none>           <none>
```

You can see from above output:

- what IP address each pod has
- what node is assigned to each pod.

By above example we will try to make a connection between:

- `ubuntu-557dc88445-lngt7` (first one) with ip address of `10.20.0.4` on the **NODE-1**
- `ubuntu-557dc88445-p8v86` (third one) with ip address of `10.20.2.4` on the **NODE-2**

#### Exec into pods

You can `exec` into the pod to run commands:

- `$ kubectl exec -it ubuntu-557dc88445-lngt7 -- /bin/bash`

Please take a look on official documentation here: [Kubernetes.io: Get shell running container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/)

#### Ping

Ping was not built into the ubuntu image but you can install it with:

- `$ apt update && apt install iputils-ping`

After that you can ping the 2nd pod and check if you can connect to another pod:

```sh
root@ubuntu-557dc88445-lngt7:/# ping 10.20.2.4 -c 4
PING 10.20.2.4 (10.20.2.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.20.2.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=0.168 ms
64 bytes from 10.20.2.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=0.169 ms
64 bytes from 10.20.2.4: icmp_seq=3 ttl=62 time=0.174 ms
64 bytes from 10.20.2.4: icmp_seq=4 ttl=62 time=0.206 ms

--- 10.20.2.4 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3104ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.168/0.179/0.206/0.015 ms
```

Comment: Dawid, thanks for your great little article and putting answers to all my questions. It helped me a lot. I am up and running with my first ever Kubernetes cluster and learning more on it now.